# How to tabulate data grouped by month AND year using Java 8 streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Assuming I have the simple POJO Meal:

```
public class Meal
{
    LocalDate mealtime;
    int calories;
}
```

which is then collected in a List:

```
List<Meals> meals;
```

How I can use streams to get a list that totals the calories consumed on a monthly basis over several years. It's very easy to tabulate based on the month alone but I want to create a bar chart spread over several years to compare the consumption of calories over time and NOT just by month.

How can this be done? Do I have to create some complex structure of Instant objects with months and Years using HashMaps of years and months or is there a better way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do it like this, using `TreeMap` to ensure that result is sorted by year and month:

```
Map<YearMonth, Integer> caloriesByMonth = meals.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(m -> YearMonth.from(m.mealtime),
                                       TreeMap::new,
                                       Collectors.summingInt(m -> m.calories)));
```

Comment: How do you then sort the YearMonth so that you can get the data in tabular order?

Comment: @StephaneGrenier I don't understand your question. Because the map is a `TreeMap`, it's already sorted by `YearMonth`, which of course sorts by year then month.

Comment: I did not realize that. I had a brain block and completely forgot about the Tree part of TreeMap, I was only thinking of Map. Thank you.